# How do I replace a string with underscores?

Tags: c++, string, replace

I'm attempting to in this code but it's not working

```
for(int i = 0; i < message_length; i++){
        char y = message[i];    

        if(y == '_'){
            cout << " ";
            }
        if(y != '_' && player_choice != y && guessed_letters[i] != y){
            cout << "-";
            }
        if(y != '_' && player_choice == y && guessed_letters[i] != y){
            cout << player_choice;
            }

        if(y != '_' && player_choice == y && guessed_letters[i] == y){
            cout << guessed_letters[i];
            }
}
```

Comment: That looks like C++. If so, please tag it as such. Also what exactly does "not working" mean. What happens, or fails to happen?

Comment: You also need to be clearer about what "replace a string with underscores" means. Try showing us sample input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Looks like a word guessing game, like fill in the blanks? But I don't see where you are trying to replace anything?